# What is the exact meaning of $I(X;Y|Z)$ in Information Theory?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, information-theory, entropy

I am wondering: is the notation $I(X;Y|Z)$ used to denote the mutual information between probabilities of $X$ and $Y|Z$ or between $X|Z$ and $Y|Z$?

Comment: Everything is conditioned on $Z$ so the latter is right.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481895/confused-about-joint-mutual-information/484032#484032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
I(X;Y|Z) = \sum_{x,y,z}p(x,y,z)\log{p(x,y|z)\over p(x|z)p(y|z)}
$$
so it isn't either of those things, but the mutual information between $X|Z$ and $Y|Z$ is a better description.

[Reference: equation (2.118) of [*Information Theory and Network Coding* by R. Yeung](http://iest2.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/~whyeung/book2/).]